# What type of connector is this one?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

What is the name of this connector?

It´s about 4mm x 8.5mm x 6.5mm

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

This is the counterpart:

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Please provide pitch and other dimensions.

Comment: It looks like a JST, but that's a brand, not a specific connector. As voltage spike says, dimensions are needed.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: pitch means the distance between the pins, and is pretty important. Measure the distance between all of them and divide by 3, for this particular connector

Comment: It´s about 2mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [JST PH type connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector) (not necessarily JST brand) with 4 pins.

Here is the [JST datasheet](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf), which gives part numbers for various members of the PH family.

Here is an image of PH family parts that I obtained from [here](https://jhiwor.aliexpress.com/store/1100599764)

[image]

Comment: Links are not working, but i still got the needed information. thank you!

Comment: @NurDerFch1846 JST is a well-known connector manufacturer. [JST PH family](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/ph-connector/).